# Работа с RequireJS в Yii

Tags: php, yii, requirejs

Добрый день!
Каким образом Вы работаете с RequireJS в Yii? Например, в кнопке ajaxSubmitButton, пишете ли логику внутри 'success' или вызываете функцию которая задана глобально в модулях RequireJS или еще как-либо? (если можно, пример)

```
echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('Save', CHtml::normalizeUrl(array('site/subscribe')),
 array(
  'dataType'=>'json',
  'type'=>'post',
  'success'=>'function(data) {
      // логика или вызов функции, заданной гл. в requrejs или еще как-либо
    }'
  ));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

И так, и так допустимо. Иногда удобнее сразу видеть код, который будет по success выполняться, а иногда код повторяется в разных местах и удобнее хранить его в отдельном скрипте. В общем, зависит от сложности проекта.